# Displaying min, max, average, and numbers entered

Tags: java

This is what i've got so far, but can't figure out how to display the number of 
numbers the user enters, I know it has something to do with the count method, but can't figure out how to implement it into this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double maximum = 0;
        double minimum = 100;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        double input = -1;
        // Main processing loop...
        do {

            // Validation loop...
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number or 0 to quit:");
                input = kb.nextDouble();
                kb.nextLine();
            } while (input > 100);

            if (input > 0) {
                count++;
                sum += input;

                if (maximum < input) {
                    maximum = input;
                }

                if (minimum > input) {
                    minimum = input;
                }
            }
        } while (input != 0);

        double average = (sum / count);

        System.out.println(
                        "The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println(
                        "Minimum of entered numbers: " + minimum);
        System.out.println(
                        "Maximum of entered numbers: " + maximum);

    }

}
```

Comment: Just do `println(count)`...

Comment: thanks, i got that to work, but when i run it, it only shows the positive numbers entered along with the minimum displaying the lowest positive number instead of a negative.

Answer (score 2):

Add the entered items to a List.

You create a list with:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you add an item to the list with:

```
list.add(input);
```

Finally you have the collection of all the inputs and better to work with.

The advantage is you can return back to all the inputs and work with them again.

To get the size you can use both of:

```
System.out.println(count);       -- using your variable
System.out.println(list.size()); -- get from the list
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to work with the input you need to save it somewhere. An array would be your best choice (array, ArrayList, ...).

1. Iterate through the array to get the lowest and highest number.
2. Divide the sum of all numbers by the size of the array to get the average.

EDIT: If you want to add negative numbers change `if (input > 0)` to `if (input != 0)` (I'm guessing you're adding the input into the array from here).

Answer (score 1):

just change the if condtion logic use  `if (input != 0 ) {` instead of if `if(input > 0 )`

try like below.

```
              if (input != 0 ) {
....
}

System.out.println("User enters total Numbers: "+count);
```